# what does a high optimal shrinkage value indicate?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

My optimal shrinkage value is high after comparing the MSE for different combinations of parameters. I'm wondering what does it mean to the data structure or signal structure? Can I say this dataset has many relevant predictors?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "optimal shrinkage value"?

Comment: The shrinkage value I used to fit the best model(lowest MSE)

Comment: You can't interpret "the shrinkage value" on its own. You need to see it in comparison to your regression parameters. And you need to explain what shrinkage you are using in the first place (Lasso, Ridge, Elastic Net, ...). And even then, there is likely no simple answer.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Well, that depends. For example, if shrinkage is zero, then ridge becomes OLS. Now if one scales the shrinkage (ridge does that but Tikhonov would not) then greater shrinkage means more injected bias.

Answer (score 1):

The shrinkage rate value $\eta$ (aka. learning rate) in the context gradient boosting does not mean anything particular individually. It helps us control the rate over which our prediction function is adapting its shape.

$\eta$ is vaguely related to the size of the dataset. Everything else being equal, a larger dataset should require a "higher" $\eta$ to converge to a stable shape than a smaller dataset; with the larger dataset we would not need to explore our function space as diligently. The shrinkage rate by itself though does not relate to the signal structure or indicates if our dataset contains relevant predictive features.